# Why img src is not displaying my picture?

Tags: html

I'd like to ask you some question:

This is my img and the picture is not displaying. If I copy-paste the img src it shows me the the picture perfectly.

```
img class="featurette-image img-responsive" src="c:\users\dagmara\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\leadMoves\leadMoves\Files\Pictures\1974302_10152306623778442_2059565629_o.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image"
```

I've tried to replace blank spaces with %20 but it still does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're referencing the image absolutely from your hard drive rather than relatively from the directory your website is in.

your image path should be something like:

```
src="../Pictures/1974302_10152306623778442_2059565629_o.jpg"
```

This will obviously depend on how your file structure is set up.

Depending on how your structure is set up you can also reference like so:

```
src="/Pictures/1974302_10152306623778442_2059565629_o.jpg"
```

Here's an article which might help:

http://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/

Comment: Yes... right now I'm testing the application in localhost.. what happens when the path changes?

Comment: The path won't change. You are creating your website in a specific directory. So you only reference files within that directory. You don't reference outside of that directory then back into it. I've updated my answer above with some more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="images/pulpit.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock" />

__WebContent
 |__index.html
 |__images
   |__pulpit.jpg
```